# Git, Windows, Linux & NTFS: "index file open failed"

Tags: linux, windows, git, ntfs

I created a git repo in Windows 7 on a NTFS partition and when opening it in Linux (Ubuntu 12 x64, dual-boot setup) I get the `index file open failed` error. How can I figure out what's wrong? The partition is mounted read-write and I've never had any other problems. Does git store data in a different format Windows vs. Linux and I need to do either a clone or some conversion? I'd really like to be able to work on the same repo in both OSs without cloning around...

Clarification: I also get `cat: index: Input/output error`
 when running the command `cat index` in the *.git* dir, so it is a NTFS related problem... but I've never had it before untill using git in a cross-systems way and I've run other apps from NTFS parts and copied files around...

Answer (score 0):

The `.git/index` file is a binary file, which describes the current workdir. Perhaps a `git fsck` is able to fix it up (move the one you have out of the way to make sure it isn't lost while you fool around, or make any expertiments on a copy of the repository). You might try to clone the repository locally, the clone might get a good copy of the file, which you could then copy over the broken one.

Possibly permission problems? Backup what is relevant, defragment the drive, run hardware checks (it might be a broken/breaking disk!).

Comment: If `cat`ting it gives an `EIO` error, `git fsck` isn't going to be able to help any.

Comment: @hobbs indeed! I've just given up on this and just use a repo in windows and another on in linux both synced to a remote repo ...if it's a driver issues I just don't have the time and skills to debug such a thing so better to go around it...

Comment: @hobbs, if the file is mangled, moving it out of the way and recreating _should_ help.

Answer (score 0):

Either your Linux NTFS driver is broken, or you have filesystem corruption, or both. Reboot to Windows and run the disk checking utility, then see how things stand when it finishes.